# Find the radius of the smallest circle in terms of the side of the square.

Tags: geometry, circles

The side length of the square is $a$. Two different quadrants are inscribed in it as follows. A small red circle is also inscribed between them.

Find the radius of the smallest circle (red one) in terms of '$a$' only.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$r=\frac{3^2-2^2\sqrt{2}}{7^2} a$.

Take $a=1$ to simplify. To find $r$, find the solution to the following that has $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$:

$$x^2+y^2 = (1+r)^2\\
(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2 = (\sqrt{2}-1+r)^2\\
x = 1-r .$$
$x,y$ represent the center of the smaller circle, $r$ is the radius. There are two solutions, only one has $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$. Since I took $a=1$ to simplify, I need to scale the answer by $a$, which gives the answer above.

Comment: Do you mean $r=\frac{9-4\sqrt{2}}{7^2} a$? Cheers.

Comment: Yes @oen, good catch, I meant to write $2^2$. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. (+1)